# sql server 2008: setting default location for mdf/ldf

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I create a new database, by default the files are saved to `c:\program files...` but I would like them by default to be saved into a different location WITHOUT having to adjust anything. Is there a way to have this done by default?

Perhaps there's some stored system procedure that I would have to change?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In SSMS, right click on the server and choose "Properties". On the "Database Settings" page of the Server Properties window, specify your new locations for data and log files.

[image]

You could also do this with T-SQL by writing directly to the registry:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultData', REG_SZ, N'E:\YourData'
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultLog', REG_SZ, N'E:\YourLogs'
GO
```

Comment: Is this also possible in any way when SQL-Server Service is not running? Please have a  look at following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245051/configure-sql-server-without-running-service