# Configure SQL-SERVER without running service

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, windows-server-2003

Is it possible to change the location of the temp.mdf or other files without starting SQL-Server?

I wanted to reactivate an old server but one of it's USB hard disk was been already used somewhere else. Now i'm unable to start the SQL-Server service in Configuration Manager.

The event log has following entry:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   MSSQLSERVER
Event Category: (2)
Event ID:   17207
Date:       30.08.2011
Time:       15:53:10
User:       N/A
Computer:   SQLSERV
Description:
```

> FCB::Open: Betriebssystemfehler 3(error not found) beim Erstellen oder
>   Öffnen der Datei 'M:\temp.mdf'. Diagnostizieren und korrigieren Sie
>   den Betriebssystemfehler, und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.

[Here are informations on this error.](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=SQL%20Server&ProdVer=2000.80.760.0&EvtID=17207&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&LCID=1033)

**Q:** So how can i change the location of database files that reference non existing drives without having SQL-SERVER service started? I haven't seen an option in Configuration-Manager. Or is there some kind of "safe-mode" in SQL-Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the options here in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx)

You can start up the server and amend the location of TEMPDB using an ALTER command through SQLCMD.

Alternatively you could just add another drive temporarily so that the correct path exists - TempDB is recreated on start up so just ensuring the path is available should be sufficient. You can then move the file locations if needed when the server is running.

Comment: Thank you. I have started SQL-Server via command-line: SqlServr.exe -f in single used mode. But now when i try to use `SqlCmd` i cannot connect: "Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time.
[CLIENT: <local machine>]"

Comment: Edit: i have found out that the reason was that reporting services was already running. After i've stopped it i could connect with admin-account to database-engine query.